# how to prevent message loss during page reload/refresh

Tags: javascript

I have an html/javascript web application that will be loaded by a hosting third party website which is on a different domain. There is some javascript-based communication between my web app and the hosting website.

When the user clicks on any button on my web application page,  my web app page will reload/refresh. However, during that reload/refresh time, the hosting website might be sending some messages to my app page, in that case those messages will get lost/dropped due to page reloading. 
I do not want to lose any messages. I want all messages to be received by my app after it is done refreshing or reloading. Is there any thing that the web app can do to make sure all messages are received from the hosting website?

Answer (score 0):

Load your new page content via Ajax and then replace the affected portion of the DOM -- that way your JS is never killed and yet new content is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor/rewrite/rearchitect your app so that the reload/refresh isn't necessary. I know that's not the answer you wanted to hear!

Alternatively, submit to the server a confirmation when a message is received. The server can re-send until a receipt is given.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the "rearchetict your app so that the reload/refresh isn't necessary"? meaning how that can be achieved while maintaining server-side rendering?

Comment: Well, without seeing the page I can't really go much further - but it would involve isolating the parts of the page that need to be refreshed and then update them via ajax.